# prove an equality using Fubini theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^{1}[0,1]$ with respect to Lebesgue measure ,$f\geq 0$.Show $$\int_{\left[0,1\right]}xf\left(x\right)dx=\int_{\left[0,1\right]}\left(\int_{\left[y,1\right]}f\left(x\right)dx\right)dy$$ 
where $dx$ and $dy$ denote integral with respect to lebesgue measure .

From Fubini theorem ,it's sufficient for us to prove that $\int_{\left[y,1\right]}dy=x$,but I don't know how to realize that.

Comment: There's no such thing as $\displaystyle \int_{[y,1]} \,dy$, since $y$ is a bound variable and cannot also be used as a free variable in that integral. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard trick:

$$\int_0^1 xf(x) \,dx = \int_0^1\left( \int_0^x f(x) \,dy \right)dx.$$

Now applies Fubini to get

$$\int_0^1\left( \int_0^x f(x) \,dy \right)dx = \int_0^1\left( \int_y^1 f(x) \,  dx \right) dy.$$

Remark: To make it clearer, one writes

$$\int_0^1\left( \int_0^x f(x) \, dy \right)dx = \int_0^1\left( \int_0^1  \chi (x,y)f(x) \, dy \right)dx,$$

where $\chi (x, y)$ is the characteristic function for the set 
$$\{ (x,y) : x\in [0,1], y\in [0,x]\}. $$

Then Fubini theorem gives 
$$\int_0^1\left( \int_0^1  \chi (x,y)f(x) \, dy \right)dx = \int_0^1\left( \int_0^1  \chi (x,y)f(x) \, dx \right)dy.$$

Now the result follows since

$$\int_0^1  \chi (x,y)f(x) \, dx = \int_y^1 f(x) \, dx.$$

Comment: And to justify the application of Fubini, it's not hard to see that $f$ is in $L^1([0,1] \times[0,1])$

Comment: I still don't understand the second equality.Are you using the change of variable or something else.

Comment: Got it ,thank you very much.